# Access method of an instance of a class that comes from a class template, without knowing the template values

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class template `Base<int,int>`. This class template also comes with a pure virtual method `baseMethod` that does not use or require the specific template values.

From this template I create multiple classes with specific template values. Those derived classes also inherit from `OtherBase`.

I instantiate a bunch of objects from those classes. Then all this ends up in multiple arrays of pointers to these objects, declared as arrays of pointers to objects of class `OtherBase`. These arrays are retrieved later, and I call `baseMethod` on the objects they contain. This is achieved by using a `static_cast` of each object in the array from `OtherBase` to some specific `Base<int,int>` e.g. `Base<0,2>` - because for each array, I know by design the template values of the class of the objects inside.

HERE'S THE ACTUAL QUESTION :

But what if I know want to do this more generically, i.e. for any object (so in any array) call the `baseMethod` of all the objects inside, knowing they are some kind of `Base<int,int>` but not knowing the actual template values of their class ?

Said in code :

```
template <int a, int b> class Base
{
    public:
    void baseMethod();
};
class OtherBase {};

class Foo : Base<0,1>, OtherBase {};
class Bar : Base<2,3>, OtherBase {};

OtherBase* foos[10];
OtherBase* bars[10];
OtherBase* foosOrBars[10];

/* This works. */
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Base<0,1>* pFoo = static_cast<Base<0,1>*>foos[i];
    pFoo->baseMethod();
}

/* This works. */
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Base<0,1>* pBar= static_cast<Base<2,3>*>bars[i];
    pBar->baseMethod();
}

/* How to do this though ? */
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Base<x,x>* pFooOrBar = static_cast<Base<x,x>*>foosOrBars[i];
    pFooOrBar->baseMethod();
}
```

Comment: So many words and no code in the question. Could you reword the question with code snippets? Otherwise it's very difficult to understand what you want to get.

Comment: Can you add a level of indirection and put 'baseMethod()` as a pure virtual function in a non-template base class and derive your template types from this root?  Then you can `static_cast` trivially.

Comment: You could implement a template free function `call_baseMethod(const T&)` and just call `baseMethod()` directly against the argument.

Comment: Are you storing `vector<OtherBase>` or `vector<OtherBase*>`?

Comment: Fair point, I am storing pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Instantiations of template classes are **different** classes. A template is just, well, a template used to "generate" classes that "share" logic. But they aren't sharing some sort of "base" you can use as a parameter type.
If you need to write a function treating multiple classes generically, you would:

### either write a template function:

(tailored to your question)

```
template<int a, int b>
void do_stuff(Base<a,b> b)
{
    ...
}
```

which only works for known instantiations of your Base<int,int> class:

```
do_stuff(Base<2,7>()); // works
```

### or you would have to make a non-template base class:

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseIntInt
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseIntInt() = default;
    virtual void baseMethod() = 0;
};

template<int a,int b>
class Base : public BaseIntInt
{
public:
    void baseMethod() override { std::cout << a << " - " << b << std::endl;}
};

void someFunctionTakingBase(BaseIntInt& b)
{
    b.baseMethod();
}

int main()
{
    Base<5,6> b56;
    someFunctionTakingBase(b56);
}
```

The non-template base class is imho the better solution to your problem. It's less generated binary and way more flexible.

Comment: "Have to" as in "there is no other, easier way" ?

Comment: I can't think of any. If you want to handle Base<int,int> generically, you would either have to write a template function or use a non template base class. And imho, that is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you use a template class which have fixed data types (int in your case). Why don't simply deal a and b as data of your class. This way evrything fall inisde a simple class hieararcy:

```
class Base
{
public:

   Base(int aa, int bb)
   {
     a = aa;
     b = bb;
   }
   int a;
   int b;

   virtual someMethod() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base 
{
   virtual void someMethod() { //some code here  }
};
```

Comment: Because I do not want to specify values for `a` and `b` for each instance of class `Foo` or `Bar`, but rather specify them once for the type `Foo` and once for the type `Bar`